# jQuery Hide div if price value is smaller than #2

Tags: jquery

I have this div with small price and another div (discounted) with higher price

```
<span class="ty-price" id="line_discounted_price_28797">
<bdi><span class="ty-price-num">£</span><span id="sec_discounted_price_28797" class="ty-price-num">0.99</span></bdi></span>
```

so when dicount div get higer price than above div then it should need to hide

```
<div class="ut-qty-discount">
<div class="ut-qty-discount-price"><bdi>£<span>1.79</span></bdi></div>
</div>
```

If #1 price value smaller than #2
then i need to hide #2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseFloat()` to use math operations on the characters.

To get the first number, use the `^=` (starts-with) selector on the `id`. The below means *find the element with an ID that begins with... - and get the text inside that element*:

```
let prx = $('[id^=sec_discounted_price]').text();
```

For the second number, you need to locate the first span via class, then traverse down to the second span:

```
let dsc = $('.ut-qty-discount-price>bdi>span').text();
```

Here is the working demo:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  let prx = $('[id^=sec_discounted_price]').text();
  let dsc = $('.ut-qty-discount-price>bdi>span').text();
  if (parseFloat(prx) < parseFloat(dsc) ){
    $('.ut-qty-discount-price').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ty-price" id="line_discounted_price_28797">
<bdi><span class="ty-price-num">£</span><span id="sec_discounted_price_28797" class="ty-price-num">0.99</span></bdi></span>

<div class="ut-qty-discount">
  <div class="ut-qty-discount-price"><bdi>£<span>1.79</span></bdi></div>
</div>

<button>Calculate</button>
```